# Should the "interesting" tag be abolished?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

As of the time of this writing, [Why do those Thai characters display on the web page with a long tail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7119115/why-are-those-thai-characters-display-on-the-web-page-with-a-long-tail) is tagged with [interesting](/questions/tagged/interesting). I have no idea what this tag is for; I would hope that most questions would be interesting!

Does this tag need to exist? It can't be applied objectively, and I doubt it would help anyone find anything. If not, is there a way to mass-untag questions that use it?

Comment: *> If not, is there a way to mass-untag questions that use it?* -- yess, it's called burnination and it smells really good.

Comment: Maybe there are some experts of interesting questions that are following those questions. `;-)`

Comment: +1 - This definitely falls under the "meta" tag category that Jeff wants to discontinue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Comment: I can't help it, but every time I see this picture, it reminds me of the [single man](http://i.stack.imgur.com/qjN7i.jpg).

Answer (score 9):

Good catch, I'm all for deleting/removing it. There are 26 questions tagged that way, and I don't see why the [interesting](/questions/tagged/interesting) tag would be of any help in filtering questions. After all, that's what tags are for.

Comment: The funny part is seeing questions tagged [tag:interesting] that are then closed; it seems they weren't so interesting, after all. The other funny part is that the tag is added by who asks the question; have you ever asked a question you didn't think interesting?